# RuntimeError: imageio.ffmpeg.download() has been deprecated. Use 'pip install im ageio-ffmpeg' instead.'

Tags: ffmpeg, python3, anaconda

I am getting this error when trying to import moviepy.editor.

```
    >>> import moviepy.editor
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\admin\Anaconda3\envs\myOpenCVEnv\lib\site-packages\moviepy\edit
or.py", line 26, in <module>
    imageio.plugins.ffmpeg.download()
  File "C:\Users\admin\Anaconda3\envs\myOpenCVEnv\lib\site-packages\imageio\plug
ins\ffmpeg.py", line 40, in download
    "imageio.ffmpeg.download() has been deprecated. "
RuntimeError: imageio.ffmpeg.download() has been deprecated. Use 'pip install im
ageio-ffmpeg' instead.'
>>> import imageio
>>> imageio.plugins.ffmpeg.download()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\admin\Anaconda3\envs\myOpenCVEnv\lib\site-packages\imageio\plug
ins\ffmpeg.py", line 40, in download
    "imageio.ffmpeg.download() has been deprecated. "
RuntimeError: imageio.ffmpeg.download() has been deprecated. Use 'pip install im
ageio-ffmpeg' instead.'
```

I am using Windows 7 64-bit. I am working on my conda environment. conda version: 4.6.1. python version: 3.5.3

Comment: Welcome to Super User! You can freely edit your own posts but for your protection, this must be done under the original user account.  It looks like you have created a second account, which will also interfere with your ability to comment within your thread and to accept an answer.  See [Merge my accounts](http://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts) to get your accounts merged, which will solve the problem.

Answer (score 12):

That's caused by the update of `imageio`

Use this instead:

```
sudo pip3 install imageio==2.4.1
```

Comment: This actually works. I hit and tried a lot of other options on internet, wasn't believing this will be the solution but when nothing worked tried above and it works. I misunderstood above thinking i have to upgrade the package to 2.4.1 but it actually as far as I understand means to downgrade the package to 2.4.1. the latest that was installed on my machine was 2.5.0. Once downgraded to 2.4.1 it works. Thank You